# Javascript in Chrome extension to replace certain characters

Tags: javascript

I'm using an extension called [Weboverride](http://weboverride.com/) to modify the formatting on a support site I use daily.  Here is an example of the content I'm trying to replace:

```
<div class="longdesc"><pre style="clear:both;word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-line;">Update by Beeson,Scott via the web. 

this is a web test

<test type="test">
 Content
</test>
</pre></div>
```

The browser renders it like this:

> this is a web test
>
> Content

I'm using the following javascript in the weboverride extension in an attempt to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` in hopes that it will render properly:

```
(function () {    
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("longdesc");
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        var node = nodes[n].getElementsByTagName("pre");
        node[0].textContent = node[0].textContent.replace("<", "&lt;");
    }
})();
```

Instead, it makes the code look like this:

```
<div class="longdesc"><pre style="clear:both;word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-line;">Update by Beeson,Scott via the web. 

this is a web test


 Content

</pre></div>
```

It seems to just strip out everything and I really don't understand why, especially since I haven't added the `>` replacement yet.  How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using `textContent` which strips HTML tags out. Use `innerHTML` instead.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rdw6904n/2/

```
(function () {    
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("longdesc");
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        var node = nodes[n].getElementsByTagName("pre");
        if (node.length > 0) {
            node[0].innerHTML = node[0].innerHTML.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
        }
    }
})();
```

I also added in a check to make sure your `node` array has objects in it before trying to access the first one. Not performing this check could cause your script to crash because you'd be trying to access a property (`innerHTML`/`textContent`) on `undefined` (`node[0]`)

Also, I replaced your call to `.replace` with `replace(/</g, "&lt;")` the `/g` here means global, so it will replace all instances which match `<` as opposed to just the first one.

Comment: That fixed it but it only seems to process the first instance of `<`.  Ideas? I can post another question if need be.

Comment: @DevilsAdvocate swap your call to `replace` out with `replace(/</g, "&lt;")` the `/g` here means global, so it will replace all instances which match

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.